# How tomcat “catalina stop” find and stop the process?

Tags: java, tomcat, process

How tomcat implement the catalina stop command? Does it find the process ID and kill the process or invoking any java dervice(JMX) and hat do the real work?

Answer (score 0):

It stops the server with `org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap stop`.
If it fails, it tries to kill the process using its pid.

You can see what's really happening in the `bin/catalina.sh` file.